# Firestore index merge with inequality condition?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have the following query:

```
.where("field1", "<", 10)
.where("field2", "==", false)
.where("field3", "==", "test1")
.where("field4", "==", "test2")
```

I am trying to understand why, despite the fact that there is no exact corresponding index, this query actually still works.

After some research the only explanation I found would be the [index merging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#taking_advantage_of_index_merging) feature but as per the documentation this should only work when there is no inequality condition which is not the case here. I must be missing something, why is my query successful?

Fyi, I have the following indexes with some of the fields:

```
field1 DESC field2 ASC field3 ASC
field1 DESC field2 ASC field4 ASC
```

Answer (score -2):

Since there are multiple equality filters, it looks like index merging is at play here.

In the Firestore docs, it doesn't specifically declare that inequality conditions will break the requirements for index merging.

Merging uses zig zag join alg, so the clause with the inequality will not be merged but others can. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#taking_advantage_of_index_merging) are details and requirements for index merging.

Although Cloud Firestore uses an index for every query, it does not necessarily require one index per query. For queries with multiple equality (==) clauses and, optionally, an orderBy clause, Cloud Firestore can re-use existing indexes.

It looks like the above query fits this criteria.

Comment: "The query uses only equality (=) filters", which is not the case here, so how can this still apply?

Comment: I have posted a wrong link(datastore instead of firestore), I modified the answer.can you have a look.